# Passing data in a variable from one function to another

Tags: python, variables

I'm trying to develop a solution to a coursework task my pupils have to complete and am stuck with passing variables between functions.  I have created a quiz within a function that generates the following data:

- First Name
- Last Name
- Score

I need to pass this data into a second function that will then append this data to a file (depending on the group the student is in).

My code looks like this as I have tried to pass the data as a string/list into the second function as a parameter:

```
def Quiz():
        #Code to collect user details and generate scoe (10 random   questions)    
        strSave=input("Do you want to save your score? y/n")
        if strSave.lower()=="y":
            result=(strFirstName+","+strLastName+","+str(score))
            #Stores the required data as a csv string 
            return result
            #?passes the data back?
            funcSave()
        elif strSave.lower()=="n":
            funcQuiz()
            #restarts the quiz function

def funcSave(result):
    #The function to save the score(s) to file
    group=input("Which group are you A1, A2 or A3?\n")
    if group=="A1":
        file=open("A1.txt","a")
        file.write(result)
        #error is that result is not defined
        file.close()
    elif group=="A2":
        file=open("A2.txt","a")
        file.write(strFirstName+","+strLastName+","+str(score))
        file.close()
    elif group=="A3":
        file=open("A3.txt","a")
        file.write(strFirstName+","+strLastName+","+str(score))
        file.close()
    else:
        print("unknown")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
return result #immediately ends the method, returning result to the caller

funcSave() # Is never executed because you've return'd. Would throw TypeError if it did because funcSave() needs one argument
```

You need to remove the [`return`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement) call, then actually pass the `results` variable from the `Quiz` method, like so:

```
funcSave(results)
```

You also have a typo in `Quiz`, where it calls `funcQuiz()` instead of `Quiz()` to restart.

As an aside, instead of this:

```
result=(strFirstName+","+strLastName+","+str(score))
```

You can just do this:

```
result = ','.join((strFirstName,strLastName,str(score)))
```

The `join` method in python concatenates a list of values together using the string before the `.` as the delimiter. It's more efficient than using `+` as python doesn't need to create any intermediary strings. Note that `join` expects all values to be strings, so you still need the cast on `score`.

Comment: Thanks - really helpful and explained the issue as well as solving it - Something more for me to teach my class!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
return result
#?passes the data back?
funcSave()
```

do

```
funcSave(result)
```

Also, rename your `Quiz` function to `funcQuiz`, so the restart works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are returning the data before you pass it to the funcSave function.  When you want to pass data to a function within another function, you don't want return the data.  Returning data allows you to get data out of a function, but it ends the execution of the function as well.

Try this:

```
def Quiz():
        #Code to collect user details and generate scoe (10 random   questions)    
        strSave=input("Do you want to save your score? y/n")
        if strSave.lower()=="y":
            result=(strFirstName+","+strLastName+","+str(score))
            # Pass the result to the funcSave function instead of returning it.
            funcSave(result)
        elif strSave.lower()=="n":
            # rename the funcQuiz() function to Quiz() so it is called correctly
            Quiz()
            #restarts the quiz function

def funcSave(result):
    #The function to save the score(s) to file
    group=input("Which group are you A1, A2 or A3?\n")
    if group=="A1":
        file=open("A1.txt","a")
        file.write(result)
        #error is that result is not defined
        file.close()
    elif group=="A2":
        file=open("A2.txt","a")
        file.write(strFirstName+","+strLastName+","+str(score))
        file.close()
    elif group=="A3":
        file=open("A3.txt","a")
        file.write(strFirstName+","+strLastName+","+str(score))
        file.close()
    else:
        print("unknown")
```

Comment: Thanks - added a bit of clarity to the solution above ni terms of adding the results variable as both a parameter to the function and when calling the function.  Now all I need to do is solve task 3!